# When Linear Maps Expand

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map.  When does $A$ satisfy
$$
(Ax)_i \geq x_i,\qquad \mbox{for } i=1,\dots,n?
$$

Clearly, when $A$ is diagonal with entries $A_{i,i}\geq 1$ this holds, but are there other cases also?

Comment: This is not true when $A$ is diagonal with at least one entry $A_{i,i}\ > 1$, you get a contradiction by considering an $x$ with suitable negative entries.

Comment: But why would thisnot works for $A_{i,i}=1$ then?